# Django - use same column for two foreign keys

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have three models:

```
class UserProfile:
   user_id = OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
   name = CharField

class User:
   # standard django model

class Channel:
   owner = ForeignKey(User)
```

And now, I want to get channels filtering on user name. So what I can do is:

```
Channel.objects.filter(owner__profile__name__icontains='foo')
```

But this joins User table and then joins UserProfile, which is not the best, because I would like to join UserProfile table on user_id instead (I would have one join instead of two)

I tried to add another foreign key to model like this:

```
class Channel:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        db_column='owner_id',
    )
    owner_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        UserProfile,
        db_column='owner_id',
        to_field='user_id')
```

But Django doesnt like it....

```
posts.Post: (models.E007) Field 'owner_profile' has column name 'owner_id' that is used by another field.
    HINT: Specify a 'db_column' for the field.
```

Is there any clean workaround for this?

Comment: For this to work, you'd have to assume that the User and UserProfile tables have the same ID values. There's no reason that that would be true.

Comment: No, notice to_field on second ForeignKey

Comment: Great question, experiencing a kind of same problem - I have unique `uuid` value that is mentioned in three different tables - A, B, C, and I want to have a ORM reference from C to both A and B objects using same underlying column of C.

Comment: Having same problem...

Answer (score 0):

[Django content type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) framework would do the trick

in your case:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Channel(models.Model):
    owner_ct = models.ForeignKey(to=ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True) # foreign key table indicator (User,Profile) in your case
    owner_content = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True) # uuid(foreign key) will be placed here as string
    owner_object = GenericForeignKey('owner_ct', 'owner_content') # bridge to object

class User(models.Model):
    channels = GenericRelation(to='Channel', object_id_field='owner_content', content_type_field='owner_ct',related_query_name='channels') # User.channels will be available

class Profile(models.Model):
    channels = GenericRelation(to='Channel', object_id_field='owner_content', content_type_field='owner_ct',related_query_name='channels') # Profile.channels will be available
```